# how to retrieve selected array object in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am having mongodb data like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58eb32fb58bbf720a80daf6f"),
    "RoleName" : "Admin",
    "UIList" : [ 
        {
            "UiName" : "ManageRole",
            "View" : true,
            "Edit" : false,
            "_id" : ObjectId("58eb32fb58bbf720a80daf79")
        }, 
        {
            "UiName" : "ManageBuildings",
            "View" : false,
            "Edit" : false,
            "_id" : ObjectId("58eb32fb58bbf720a80daf78")
        }, 
        {
            "UiName" : "ManageFacility",
            "View" : true,
            "Edit" : false,
            "_id" : ObjectId("58eb32fb58bbf720a80daf77")
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0,
    "Description" : "Full Control",
    "IsActive" : true
}
```

I want to retrieve only View:true in UIList under UiName:"ManageFacility" 's  how to retrieve that.

I tried to get the data following this query but it retrieve all UIList Under Uiname:,View,Edit  value.

```
db.getCollection("manage_roles_news").find(
    { _id:ObjectId("58eb32fb58bbf720a80daf6f")},
    {UIList: {$elemMatch: {UiName: "ManageFacility"}}});
```

How to retrieve that only view in UIlist under Uiname:"ManageFacility"

can anyone tell me

Comment: Try `db.getCollection("manage_roles_news").find(
    { _id:ObjectId("58eb32fb58bbf720a80daf6f")},
    {UIList: {$elemMatch: {UiName: "ManageFacility", View:true}}});`

Comment: Hi, @Veeram this query also return all the managefacility column

Comment: I want only view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is way to project individual fields from `positional/elemMatch` projection. It always resolves to array element.

You can try below aggregation to project field. The below query uses [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) operator to find the matching array values which is piped to [$arrayAtElem](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) to return the first element `(0)` and pass the matching document to [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) operator and followed by picking the `View` property.

```
db.getCollection("manage_roles_news").aggregate(
  { $match: { _id: ObjectId("58eb32fb58bbf720a80daf6f") } }, 
  { $project: { 
      _id:0,
      View: 
      { $let: { 
            vars: { 
              mElement: { 
                $arrayElemAt: [{
                            $filter: {
                                input: "$UIList",
                                as: "fElement",
                                cond: {
                                    $eq: ["$$fElement.UiName", "ManageFacility"]
                                }
                            }
                        }, 0]
                    }
                },
            in: {$cond:["$$mElement.View", 1, 0]}
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: 1. Add `_id:0` to exclude `_id` in the `$project` stage. 2 Replace   `"$$mElement.View"` with `{$cond: [ "$$mElement.View", 1, 0 ]   }`

Comment: can post this in another answer

Comment: Sorry. I didn't understand you. Do you want me to update answer with the previous comment changes ?

Comment: now my requirement is: i want the count of table. i will give id value:"ObjectId("58eb32fb58bbf720a80daf6f")", UiName:"ManageFacilty",and View:"true".   If the three conditions are satisfies return 1 or else. 0

Comment: db.getCollection("manage_roles_news").find( { _id:ObjectId("58eb32fb58bbf720a80daf6f")}, {UIList: {$elemMatch: {UiName: "ManageFacility", View:true}}});

Comment: 1st enter view:true next enter view:false and see the result you will understand

Comment: Use `db.getCollection("manage_roles_news").count( { _id:ObjectId("58eb32fb58bbf720a80daf6f"), UIList: {$elemMatch: {UiName: "ManageFacility", View:true}}});`. This will give you the count if condition matches or else 0.